# how to stream through mms://

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, mms

There are some posts about this, but so far, i haven't seen any good answer. Is there a way i can stream audio from mms:// uris with Android?. MediaPlayer seems not to like these streams. Also changing mms:// with http or rtsp doesn't work either. Did someone find a workaround to this?. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download Android NDK
2. Then download modified libmms and libffmpeg at http://radiotime.com/apps/android.aspx
3. basically you has to have 2 threads:

   - 1st thread for downloading the audio data from mms station then write to a wma file
   - 2nd thread decode this wma to PCM data using the libffmpeg.

Comment: hmm, i'm not familiar with NDK, but,.. i guess i will have to dig on it :-). Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This seems to be the only real solution to the mms support lacking.. however the modified libraries you mention seem to have vanished and I can't find them anywhere..If you have them or know where they can be found atm please share that info.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

To save some time you can use the following library for playing mms streams:
[FFMpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer).

It has the same interface as the android MediaPlayer so its easy to work with and it comes with optional prebuilt binaries too.

I use it in my own mms streaming application and I haven't had any problems.

Comment: It looks like finally we have a solution for this, that does´t need to go deep into NDK like accepted answer. I will take a look and will update accordingly. Thanks!