# MMS protocol [Android Application]

Tags: android, protocols, audio-streaming, mms, internet-radio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to stream through mms://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231893/how-to-stream-through-mms)

I wish to create an application that would play online radio stations.
There are some radio online stations which runs on mms protocol.
For example, the url (mms://119.2.60.76:8080 ) when clicked opens in windows medai player, i want to buffer this audi and then my android application would play it.
I am not being able to set the datasource for media player as it annoys me with Unknown Host Protocol.
Please help me.

Comment: Forget it Android doesn't support

Comment: I guess it related to the underlying Java URL class the Android is using. This class can't deal with "non-standard" protocols such mms. Try using another class.

Comment: If it doesn't support the protocol, then you shouldn't try to add it, but figure out other ways to do it. Refer to the MediaPlayer class and find out what is and what is not supported.